# How to find asymptotic variance for mle with ln

Tags: statistics, asymptotics, variance, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I have $X_1,...,X_n$ that are iid random variables with density function $$f(x) = {\alpha}x^{\alpha-1}$$

where $0<x<1$ and ${\alpha}$ is an unknown parameter.

The MLE estimator I got was $\frac{-n}{ln(n)+ln(\overline{X})}$. How do I find this MLE's asymptotic variance? I am especially stuck because of the ln function with the X bar.

Answer (score 1):

The asymptotic variance of the MLE is given by $I(\alpha)^{-1}$ where $I(\alpha)$ is the Fisher information, namely,
$$
I(\alpha)=-nE\left(\frac{d^2}{d\alpha^2}\log f(X;\alpha)\right)=-nE(-\alpha^{-2})=\frac{n}{\alpha^2}
$$
It follows that the asymptiotic variance is 
$$
\frac{\alpha^2}{n}.
$$